# Issue with Updating Reactive State of a Variable During API Call in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm facing a challenge in updating a reactive state within a function that handles an API call inside a Vue.js component. In my project, I'm using Vue 3 and Axios for API calls.

Here's the context:

I have a component named EmployeesListView that needs to fetch and display a list of employees. I've defined a reactive state called loading in the component, and I'm trying to set it to true at the beginning of the API call and then back to false upon completion of the call. However, it seems that the modification inside the apiCaller function doesn't affect the reactive state of the component.

Here's the relevant code in my EmployeesListView component:

```js
<script>
import backendService from "@/utils/backendService";

export default {
  name: "EmployeesListView",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      employees: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getEmployees() {
      const config = {
        dataTarget: this.employees,
        loader: this.loading,
      };

      // The API call should somehow modify `config.loader`
      backendService.getEmployees(config);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getEmployees();
  },
  // ... other component details
};
</script>
```

In my backendService service, I have the apiCaller function that performs the API call. Inside this function, I'm trying to modify the config.loader variable from false to true at the start of the call and back to false at the end:

```js
// ... Other imports and definitions

function apiCaller(method, endpoint, requestData, config) {
    if (config.loader !== undefined && config.loader !== null) {
        config.loader = true; // This doesn't seem to affect the reactive state of the component
    }

    axios({
        method: method,
        url: endpoint,
        data: requestData,
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (config.dataTarget) {
                Object.assign(config.dataTarget, response.data);
            }

            // Other response handling code...
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // Error handling...
        })
        .finally(() => {
            if (config.loader !== undefined && config.loader !== null) {
                config.loader = false; // This doesn't seem to affect the reactive state of the component
            }
        });
}

// ... Other definitions

const backendService = {
    getEmployees: (config) => {
        // Some preliminary operations...

        apiCaller("get", endpoint, null, config);
    },
};

export default backendService;
```

Despite the changes to config.loader inside apiCaller, it seems that the reactive state of the EmployeesListView component isn't updated as I would expect.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has suggestions on how to tackle this situation? I appreciate any help or advice on this. Thank you very much in advance!